# Transfer existing email to new postfix/dovecot server via POP3

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, dovecot, pop3

I have to build a new email server with dovecot/postfix on CentOS because an existing supplier is becoming too erratic with their billing. I can do that but I am worried for a small problem.

If I create a new server before I transfer the MX records and DNS, can I connect to the existing server via POP3 using the new server as a client and "download" all the email that way?

Comment: nevermind I found http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Migration/Dsync

Comment: Please answer your question when it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found [dsync tool](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Migration/Dsync) from Dovecot wiki. As alternative, you can also use [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/).